# How do I show the username field in the user edit form?

Tags: users

I need to show username textfield in user edit form. Normally, it shows only for administrator user. How do I show this for all users' edit form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to admin/people/permissions and select the *Change own username* for the roles you need to be able to change their username.

> [image: screenshot]